# How to prevent sharing of static variables in inherited classes?

Tags: php, inheritance, static

Consider `Model.php`:

```
class Model {
    protected static $class_name;
    protected static $table_name;

    protected $id;

    public static function initialize() {
        static::$class_name = get_called_class();
        static::$table_name = strtolower(static::$class_name).'s';
    }
}
```

and its children, `User.php` and `Product.php`:

```
class User extends Model {
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
}
User::initialize();

class Product extends Model {
    protected $name;
    protected $price;
}
Product::initialize();
```

Since every `User` or `Product` will have the same `$class_name` and `$table_name`, it makes sense to make them `static`. The actual values are assigned when `initialize()` method is called on the child model (e.g. `User::initialize();` and `Product::initialize();`).

## Problem

I would expect to end up with the following:

```
User    -> $class_name -> 'User',    $table_name -> 'users'
Product -> $class_name -> 'Product', $table_name -> 'products'
```

Yet I get the following:

```
User    -> $class_name -> 'User',    $table_name -> 'users'
Product -> $class_name -> 'User',    $table_name -> 'users'
```

**How is this possible given that I am using late static binding with `static::`? And how can this be fixed?** My goal is for `User` and `Product` to have independent `class_name` and `table_name`, but still keep both variables **`static`**, hopefully *without redeclaring them on each model*, be it `User`, `Product` or any other!

Comment: Anyone has an idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `Product::initialize` is called, `Model::$class_name` is set to `"Product"` and `Model::$table_name` to `"products"`. When `User::initialize` is called, `Model::$class_name` and `Model::$table_name` are overwritten with `"User"` and `"users"`.

The static in initialize would only make a difference, if those attributes were defined in the sub classes.

The second part of your question you answered yourself, either redeclare them or make them non-static.

**Edit**

You could use a map in combination with accessors to fake sub-class local inherited static properties (I hope I just made that up).

```
class Foo {
        private static $class_names = [];
        private static $table_names = [];

        public static function getClassName() {
                return self::$class_names[static::class];
        }

        public static function getTableName() {
                return self::$table_names[static::class];
        }

        public static function initialize() {
                self::$class_names[static::class] = static::class;
                self::$table_names[static::class] = strtolower(static::class).'s';
        }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
}
Bar::initialize();

class Baz extends Foo {
}
Baz::initialize();

echo Bar::getTableName() . " " . Bar::getClassName() . "\n";
echo Baz::getTableName() . " " . Baz::getClassName() . "\n";
```

Declaring dynamic static properties does sadly not work in PHP 7.

Comment: To clarify, is there truly no any other option at all in making `static` variable be differentiated between different subclasses?

Comment: I updated my answer. Why do you even want to store class name and table, when both can easily be derived from the name of class?

Comment: Thank you. The reason for storing them as `static` is that `Model` class has many `static` and non-static methods, and each needs to access `class_name` and `table_name`. I could declare them in function scope every time that function is called, but then the code would be repeated across all functions. Do you think that with the later approach, local `class_name` and `table_name` would be initialized in a function properly, based on whether the call came from `User` or `Product` subclass?

Comment: Yes, they will. I would create two static functions that, using late static binding, compute table and class name and just use them in all other methods, e.g. `public static function() getTableName{ return strtolower(static::class).'s'; }`

Answer (score -1):

after read the accepted answer, i have solutions with workaround to use classCallerContainer.

```
class ParentClass{

    protected static $container = [];


    protected static function setIndependentProperty($string){
        //# stored the the caller class as the bank
        static::$container[get_called_class()] = $string;
    }
    protected static function getIndependentProperty(){

        //# collect the value in container base on the caller class
        return static::$container[get_called_class()] ?? "";
    }


}
```