# PHP: how to make static inherited property independent to other child

Tags: php, oop

What we want to achieve is having inherited ChildrenA::$property  independent to other class. it becomes independent If declare the ChildrenA::$property in class default value.

```
//# ============ Declare class
    Class ParentClass{
        public static $property = ["parent"=>"im Parent"];
    }

    Class ChildrenA extends  ParentClass {
        //# must put in init because in real case the value is an expression
        public static function init(){
            static::$property["childrenA"] = "Im Children A";
        }
    }
    Class ChildrenB extends  ParentClass {
}
//# =============================================

//# in real case this called in app singleton
ChildrenA::init();

var_dump(ChildrenB::$property);

var_dump(ParentClass::$property);
```

var_dump Result: ParentClass and ChildrenB is also having ChildrenA static propert

```
array(2) {
  'parent' =>
  string(9) "im Parent"
  'childrenA' =>
  string(13) "Im Children A"
}
```

how to give independent to children A

Answer (score 0):

its **impossible** to have dynamic static inheritance property mentioned below link.
but it gives idea to store in classCallerContainer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568670/how-to-prevent-sharing-of-static-variables-in-inherited-classes/55609794#55609794) is my answer and code example in other post